# Unbelievable CSS div jump

Tags: html, css

See it or yourself! The meal-category-box div has an inexplicable jump from the title to the rest of the content. We can't work it out?

[My code](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lc5y/) is also shown here:

```css
/* Begin Base */

body {
    color: #245a03;
    background-color: #e7f5df;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue-Light",
    "HelveticaNeue", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>


<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>MealMarket</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >

    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"/>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voces' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body class="">

    <div id="container">

        
        <div id="header">
         <a href="/"><h1>Meal Market</h1>
            <span>Share food, get food, more merry mealtimes</span></a>
        </div>

        
        

        <div id="main" role="main" class="container">
            




<div id="user-info">

    

        <img src="/static/images/pics/profile-default.jpg">

    


    <div id="user-column-options">
        <h3 style="word-wrap:break-word;">
            Matt</h3>

        <p>Credits: 10</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/meals/new/">Make meal</a></li>
            <li><a href="/meals">Find meal</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="">Past meals</a></li>-->
        </ul>
    </div>


    
</div> 

<!-- End user info column -->
<div id="stream">



    

    

    
<!-- Start user's coming hosted meals div -->
    <div class="meal-category-box">
        <h4>Coming Meals that You&#39;re Cooking</h4><br />

        

            <div class="meal-box-small">
                <div class="meal-details">
                    <p><h5><a href="/meals/matt/22/Apr/2012/05:30">
                        Fungus food</a></h5>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;April 22, 2012, 5:30 a.m.
                    </p>
                    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;(View map)</p>
                    <p style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            
                            <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="emphasis-box"><a href="/meals/matt/22/Apr/2012/05:30?mealsignup=true" class="btn">Click to attend this meal</a></div>
                            
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
        

            <div class="meal-box-small">
                <div class="meal-details">
                    <p><h5><a href="/meals/matt/21/Apr/2012/19:00">
                        Lentil stew</a></h5>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;April 21, 2012, 7 p.m.
                    </p>
                    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;(View map)</p>
                    <p style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            
                            <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="emphasis-box"><a href="/meals/matt/21/Apr/2012/19:00?mealsignup=true" class="btn">Click to attend this meal</a></div>
                            
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
        
        
    </div>    
    <!-- End user's coming hosted meals div -->



    

    <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>


    <!-- Start other coming meals div -->

    <div class="meal-category-box">
        <h4>Other Upcoming Meal Invites</h4>

        
        <div class="meal-box">
            <img src="">
            <div class="meal-details">
                <p><h5><a href="/meals/jervin/13/Apr/2012/00:30">
                    Great flippin&#39; food</a></h5>
                </p>
                <p>April 13, 2012, 12:30 a.m.<p>
                <p> (View map)</p>
                <p>Cooked by 
                    <a href="/users/jervin/">
                    jervin</a>
                </p>
        
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="emphasis-box"><a href="/meals/jervin/13/Apr/2012/00:30?mealsignup=true" class="btn">Click to attend this meal</a></div>
            </div>    
        </div>                            
        
        <div class="meal-box">
            <img src="">
            <div class="meal-details">
                <p><h5><a href="/meals/jervin/29/Apr/2012/04:30">
                    Veggie curry</a></h5>
                </p>
                <p>April 29, 2012, 4:30 a.m.<p>
                <p> (View map)</p>
                <p>Cooked by 
                    <a href="/users/jervin/">
                    jervin</a>
                </p>
        
                <div style="margin-top: 20px;" class="emphasis-box"><a href="/meals/jervin/29/Apr/2012/04:30?mealsignup=true" class="btn">Click to attend this meal</a></div>
            </div>    
        </div>                            
        

    </div>
    <!-- End other coming meals div -->
    

</div>    

<div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>


        </div>


        <div id="clearer">&nbsp;</div>


            <footer class="footer">
            <hr>
            <ul id="footer-links">
                <li><a href="/about">About / FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a href="/legal">Privacy / Legal</a></li>
                <li><a href="/media">Media</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of #container -->


    
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/static/js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!--<script defer src="/static/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/static/js/script.js"></script>-->
    

        
    <script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse({toggle: false});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // On click...
    $("#cross-icon").click(function() {
    $('#new-user-box p').slideUp("slow")
      $('#new-user-box').slideUp("slow");
    
    });
    </script>


    <script> // Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID
        window._gaq = [['_setAccount','UAXXXXXXXX1'],['_trackPageview'],['_trackPageLoadTime']];
        Modernizr.load({
            load: ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
        });
    </script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
    <![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code in your question. Also, I see no jumping. Please better explain what you are referring to.

Comment: Don't just dump all your code in jsfiddle, that's not how it works. jsfiddle provides you already with a doctype, head and body. It also has separate css and javascript areas just for that. Also, you can add your scripts in resources if they're not in the dropdown list, such as extra css or jquery plugins. Please work a bit more on your question if you want solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `clear: both;` from the style for `.meal-box-small`.

`#user-column-options` is set to `float: left;`, so the `clear: both;` causes `.meal-box-small` to move below that.

Answer (score 1):

How about the 70px bottom margin on your `#header`? (The Developer Tools: use them.)

[image]

Comment: I actually think he was referring to the gap between `Coming Meals that Your Cooking` and `Fungus Food`. Clarification would help. This is caused by the sidebar where the picture is. It is floated and he probably clears the float prematurely.

Comment: @mrtsherman You're probably correct. In this case, Ryan P's answer is the winner.

Answer (score 0):

`div#header` has a `margin-bottom` of 70px. Decrease that to lessen the space between your title and content.

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in your HTML:

```
<!-- Start user's coming hosted meals div -->
    <div class="meal-category-box">
        <h4>Coming Meals that You&#39;re Cooking</h4>
            <div class="meal-box">
                <div class="meal-details">
```

Just change the div with the class meal-box-small to the class meal-box and all is fine.